# functions in a dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I would like to create a list of functions and put them in a dataframe. It makes it easier for me to manipulate the functions for the rest of my work. I want to put the ecdf and the quantile functions while grouping on a columns of characters/factors.

I did something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
quantilef = function(x) {
  qf = function(p){
    return(quantile(x, probs = p))
  }
  return(qf)
}

ecdfdf = iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(ecdf_ = list(ecdf(Sepal.Length)),
            qf_ = list(quantilef(x = Sepal.Length)))
```

The ecdf works as expected:

```
> ecdfdf %>% mutate(p = map_dbl(.x = ecdf_, .f = ~.x(5)))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Species    ecdf_  qf_        p
  <fct>      <list> <list> <dbl>
1 setosa     <ecdf> <fn>    0.56
2 versicolor <ecdf> <fn>    0.06
3 virginica  <ecdf> <fn>    0.02
```

But the quantile one gives `NA`:

```
> ecdfdf %>% mutate(q10 = map_dbl(.x = qf_, .f = ~.x(0.5)))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Species    ecdf_  qf_      q10
  <fct>      <list> <list> <dbl>
1 setosa     <ecdf> <fn>      NA
2 versicolor <ecdf> <fn>      NA
3 virginica  <ecdf> <fn>      NA
```

I know that the `quantilef` works, because it works outside the dataframe:

```
> qfsl = quantilef(x = iris$Sepal.Length)
> qfsl(0.5)
50% 
5.8
```

What is going on? How do i get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that when you are creating the list of functions for `qf_`, you are passing in a parameter, `x` which is lazily evaluated. When you go to call the function, the `x` no longer exists in the calling environment.

One way round this is to wrap `x` in a `quosure` which is evaluated at the point your function is called.

Here's a reprex:

```r
library(tidyverse)

quantilef = function(x) {
  y <- rlang::new_quosure(x)
  qf <- function(p){
    return(quantile(rlang::eval_tidy(y), probs = p))
  }
  return(qf)
}

ecdfdf = iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(ecdf_ = list(ecdf(Sepal.Length)),
            qf_ = list(quantilef(x = Sepal.Length)))

ecdfdf %>% mutate(q10 = map_dbl(.x = qf_, .f = ~.x(0.5)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   Species    ecdf_  qf_      q10
#>   <fct>      <list> <list> <dbl>
#> 1 setosa     <ecdf> <fn>     5  
#> 2 versicolor <ecdf> <fn>     5.9
#> 3 virginica  <ecdf> <fn>     6.5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. So another thing I noticed, if I do `write_rds(ecdf, f="test.rds")` using my function, it seems to save the whole dataframe (it's 1.4GB in may case). whereas in your case it's only 70MB, which means it's only keeping the vector `Sepal.Length` in memory and not the whole dataframe.